# What's the difference between timer and rbtimer in uWSGI?

Tags: python, timer, uwsgi

I'm looking to add simple repeating tasks to my current application and I'm looking at the uwsgi signals api and there are two decorators `@timer` and `@rbtimer`. I've tried looking through the doc and even the python source at least but it appears it's probably more low level than that somewhere in the c implementation.

I'm familiar with the concept of a red-black tree but I'm not sure how that would relate to timers. If someone could clear things up or point me to the doc I might have missed I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@timer uses kernel-level facilities, so they are limited in the maximum number of timers you can create.

@rbtimer is completely userspace so you can create an unlimited number of timers at the cost of less precision

Comment: Thanks. And I'm just guessing here but based on your username and the the name I see on all the source commits, thanks for uWSGI!

Comment: Do you think there's a performance difference between the two?